# A particular family of symmetric functions (sums of powers of sums of subsets)

Tags: reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra, symmetric-functions

For any $m,k$ define
$$ f_{m,k}(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = \sum_{1\le i_1<i_2<\cdots<i_m\le n} (x_{i_1}+\cdots+x_{i_m})^k. $$

Do these symmetric polynomials have a name and any theory?

Comment: These remind me of those: https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.02943 . Note that these are symmetric polynomials, not symmetric functions, since they aren't per-se well-defined in infinitely many variables.

Comment: @darijgrinberg These polynomials can be written uniquely in terms of power-sum symmetric polynomials with rational coefficients independent of $n$. Doesn't that mean they can extended to symmetric functions over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Like Darij, I also noticed that these are precisely the polynomials that show up in the expansion of the Chern character of $\bigwedge^k V$ in terms of the Chern roots. As far as the second remark, the coefficients do depend on $n$. For example, in the symmetric monomial basis, $x_1^k$ has coefficient $\binom{n-1}{m-1}$. Is there some normalization missing?

Comment: @GjergjiZaimi My apology to you and darij.  I had conflicting notation in my application and my question. The coefficients do depend on $n$ and I don't think there is suitable normalization that is only a function of $n$.

Comment: Actually, now I recall there was some discussion of these symmetric polynomials in the comments of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2132016/generalization-of-the-well-known-combinatorial-identity-sum-j-0n-1j-n/2145263?noredirect=1#comment4416174_2145263 .